# Specific regex name pattern that allows for various name from other countries

Tags: regex

Hoping for some help I want to have a pattern that matches names with the following format.

```
Surname, Firstname othername othername

My pattern = "^[\\p{L} .'-]+[,\s][\\p{L} .'-]+$"
```

My issue is that it works but I want to restrict whitespaces in the surname part.

IE so Johnson Fredrick, Whatever - wouldn't be found

I tried `"^([\\p{L} .'-]+[^\s][,\s][\\p{L} .'-]+$"` but no such luck...

Thanks!

Comment: Provide examples of some valid and invalid inputs.

Comment: Oh sorry, first time using. 
Got it working now via @aelor.
Will ensure I do this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the space from the first block of code:

```
My pattern = "^[\\p{L}.'-]+[,\s][\\p{L} .'-]+$"
```